# How to customise Facebook shares

Tags: facebook

I've successfully added a Share button to my website using the following code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

It produces a popup with a link to the `og:url` along with the title of the linked page and a picture from it, which I can then post, and it shows up on my Facebook.

I am having 3 issues with this:

1. I've update the `og:url` and `data-href` after page load, using jquery, but the new values get ignored when I Share.
2. the `og:title`, `og:description`, and `og:image` don't appear to be used at all.
3. Sometimes I'd like to Share some custom text (and images if possible) without any url.

I'm aware that Facebook provide other tools/APIs that provide more versatility but it seems that would mean my site would have to go through a review process, and I'd have to code for security. This is not an option and I want to stick to the popup method.

Hope someone can help. Many thanks.

Comment: The last time I checked the Facebook share logic does not read changes made to the DOM by JS; it only recognises the meta available when the page initially loads. This is why your shared values do not change. As far as I'm aware theres no workaround for this without using the Facebook API to implement sharing.

Comment: Facebook will scrape the URL separately from when the user loads the page. And it will not execute Javascript when it does.

Comment: 3.) On user profiles - not possible any more. You can only use the dialogs Facebook provides, but none of them allows for posting without a URL. On your own pages - via API, with a page access token.

Answer (score 0):

If the tags do not change when posting, refresh (and test) the tags in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Dynamically created Open Graph tags (with JavaScript) will be ignored, the tags have to be in the original page source.